# vueRouter solo me carga estilos y clases pero nada funciona

Tags: vue.js

Si utilizo $router.push o router-link, me redirige al componente que necesito o a la pagina que quiero. Pero las funciones, metodos y eventos del componente llamado no funcionan, solo queda funcionando el navbar y footer. **Tambien si recargo la pagina, todo vuelve a funcionar.**
El inspector tampoco me lanza error.

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Routes from './routes'
import App from './componentes/App.vue'
import Axios from 'axios'
import Toastr from 'toastr'
import * as VueGoogleMaps from 'vue2-google-maps'
Vue.use(VueRouter)
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: Routes,
    // mode: 'history'
});

const app = new Vue({
  router,
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

**app.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <encabezado></encabezado>
    <!-- <keep-alive> -->
        <router-view></router-view>
    <!-- </keep-alive> -->
  </div>
</template>
<script>

import { isMobile } from 'mobile-device-detect'
import encabezado from './encabezado.vue'
export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    encabezado
  },
  data () {
    return {
      movil: isMobile,
    }
  },
  mounted() {

  },
  methods: {

  }

}
</script>
```

**route.js**

```
import Financiero from './componentes/vistas/financiero.vue';
import Principal from './componentes/principal/principal.vue';
export default [
  {
    path: '/financiero',
    component: Financiero,
    name: 'Financiero'
  },
  { path: '/principal', component: Principal, name: 'principal' },
]
```

**componente**

```
<template>
  <div :class="{dvContainer:movil}">
      <div v-if="movil" class="fixed-action-btn">
        <a class="btn-floating btn-large sidenav-trigger pulse waves-effect waves-light purple darken-3" href="#" data-target="slide-out">
          <i class="large material-icons">chat</i>
        </a>
      </div>
    <ul id="slide-out" class="collapsible" :class="{sidenav: movil, enCelularSide: movil, menuLateral: !movil }" style="padding-bottom: 30px !important;">
      <li class="active">
        <div class="collapsible-header" ><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>Analisar proyecto</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body cuerpoItemColapse">
          <mapa></mapa>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li >
        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">assignment</i>Resume n</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body cuerpoItemColapse">
          <div class="col s10" style="margin: 10px; margin-right: 0;">
            <resumen :movil="movil"></resumen>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>


<script>

import evaluacion from '../navegacion/evaluacion.vue'
import mapa from '../navegacion/mapa.vue'
import resumen from '../navegacion/resumen.vue'


export default{
  components:{
    evaluacion,
    mapa,
    resumen,
  },
  data(){
      return{
          movil: isMobile,
          iconExcelPath: require('./icono_excel.jpg')
      }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Necesitariamos por lo menos ver algun componente y como haces las llamadas al router. Esto deberia funcionar sin problemas, hay algo mas, pero con la info que das es poco lo que podemos hacer. Si haces  un [mcve], mucho mejor

Comment: Ahi edite y coloque componentes y acceso a routes.